What is a natural cubic "B-spline"?
I recently learned that natural cubic splines are strictly distinct from natural cubic B-splines while studying spline methods. It appears that natural cubic B-splines are obtained by adding additional boundary conditions to the basis functions formed by B-splines.
I have two questions related to this:
Form of Natural Cubic B-spline Basis: What form does the natural cubic B-spline basis take? I am curious if it has an exact form of basis like B-splines.
Degrees of Freedom: In the ns function (which generates natural cubic B-spline basis) of the splines package in R, the number of knots is k = df - 1 when there is no intercept. On the other hand, the bs function (which generates cubic B-spline basis) has k = df - d. I am curious why the number of knots for natural cubic B-splines, despite depending on the B-spline basis, does not depend on the degree.
I have searched through various resources, but most do not distinguish between natural cubic splines and natural cubic B-splines, which makes it difficult to find accurate information. Additionally, while I have found some papers that use natural cubic B-splines, they typically only mention their use without providing the theoretical background.
